# android smspopup

Tags: android, android-emulator

i downloaded the smspopup app for android from [android-smspopup](http://code.google.com/p/android-smspopup/source/checkout) using svn, now i opened the project in eclipse. i did the following:
    1) Build Project;
    2) Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties;
    3) Project -> Clean.

Now, for the following java classes:
    1) SmsPopupActivity;
    2) SmsPopupPager.

It says that it cannot resolve the following:

```
import com.jakewharton.android.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator;
```

I downloaded the [Android-ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/downloads). Now, i try to add it using the Properties -> Android -> Add Library. But it does not let me add anything. Please can you help me to resolve this problem... I would really appreciate if someone could explain how to solve this problem step-by-step. Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Comment: Perhaps your workspace already have a project named library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered the same problem with you,and i finally found the solution on the site of https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator.

Android-ViewPagerIndicator is presented as an Android library project. A standalone JAR is not possible due to the theming capabilities offered by the indicator widgets.

You can include this project by referencing it as a library project in Eclipse or ant.

Comment: can you show step by step how you did it? because whenever i try to add using properties -> android -> library add, it does not let me add anything... thanks!

Comment: Hope the problem has been solved.1.Let the viewpagerindicator project as an android library,just select the check box Is Library；2,Add viewpagerindicator as an library of the SmsPopupConfigActivity,using properties->android->library-add